# Error accessing inherited class method with @ViewChild in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, viewchild

I'm facing an issue with my Angular application. I have a component hierarchy where I'm trying to access a method from an inherited class using @ViewChild, but I'm encountering an error. It works well when the isRegistrationCompleted method is directly inside ProductRegistrationComponent.

Error:

```
screen-product-registration.component.ts:31 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isRegistrationCompleted')
```

Here's a simplified version of my code structure:

*screen-product-registration.component.html*

```
<div class="row full-height">        
   <app-product-registration #productRegistration></app-product-registration>
</div>
```

*ScreenProductRegistrationComponent*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-registration-screen',
  templateUrl: './product-registration-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-registration-screen.component.css']
})
export class ProductRegistrationScreenComponent implements OnInit{ 
  
  @ViewChild(ProductRegistrationComponent) productRegistration!: ProductRegistrationComponent;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.startContinuousUpdate();
  }        

  startContinuousUpdate() {

    setInterval(() => {      
      const listNeedsLoading = this.productRegistration.isRegistrationCompleted(); 

      if (listNeedsLoading) {
        console.log("Entered inside IF");
      }
    }, 1000);     
  }
}
```

*product-registration.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-registration',
  templateUrl: './product-registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-registration.component.css']
})
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProductRegistrationComponent extends ProductService{  

}
```

*product.service.ts*

```
export class ProductService {

  private registrationCompleted: boolean = false;

  isRegistrationCompleted(){
    return this.registrationCompleted;
  }

  loadProducts() {   
   console.log("it works");
   this.registrationCompleted = !this.registrationCompleted;
  }
}
```

[image: UML Diagram from Product Registration Project]

Comment: If I remember correctly the property defined through `ViewChild` is accessible starting from `ngViewInit` hook

Comment: @DmitryS. Can you exemplify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because you're trying to access method of the child component `ProductRegistrationComponent` on a level of the `OnInit` lifecycle hook. At that moment your `productRegistration` variable is declared but not defined. You'll get access to the child component reference and its methods only in the `AfterViewInit` hook.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-registration-screen',
  templateUrl: './product-registration-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-registration-screen.component.css']
})
export class ProductRegistrationScreenComponent implements AfterViewInit{ 
  
  @ViewChild(ProductRegistrationComponent) productRegistration!: ProductRegistrationComponent;
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.startContinuousUpdate();
  }        

  startContinuousUpdate() {

    setInterval(() => {      
      const listNeedsLoading = this.productRegistration.isRegistrationCompleted(); 

      if (listNeedsLoading) {
        console.log("Entered inside IF");
      }
    }, 1000);     
  }
}
```